# $f(x) = x f(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x>0$

Tags: functional-equations

For $x>0$, $f(x)>0$  and continuous. Also $$f(x)=xf\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg).$$ The function $f(x)=x \ \text{for} \ x\in(0,1]$ and $f(x)=1 \ \text{for} \ x>1$ certainly satisfies the above conditions. Is this the unique function satisfying the above conditions? Or what is  another example function?

Thanks

Comment: How about arbitrary $f$ for $0 < x <1$, $f(1) = 1$, and $f(x) = x f(x^{-1})$ for $x > 1$?

Comment: For the record, the functions mentioned by @HansEngler are **all** the solutions to the functional equation (with the exception that $ f ( 1 ) $ can be chosen arbitrarily). And those solutions are continuous iff the function chosen on $ ( 0 , 1 ) $ is continuous and its limit when $ x \to 1 ^ - $ exists, and is equal to $ f ( 1 ) $.

Comment: Another class of solutions: $f(x)=C\sqrt{x}.$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&f(x)=xf\Big(\frac 1 x\Big), f: \mathbb{R^{+}} \to \mathbb{R^{+}}\text{ and Continuous.} \\
\ \\
&\text{if } f \equiv c: \\
&c=xc \Rightarrow c=0, \text{ Contradiction.(By $f: \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R^+}$.)} \\
\therefore \; & f \not\equiv c. \\
\end{align}
This shows that the function isn't constant...

I just thought about another form of this function and found another one.

[image]

I think these 2 functions satisfy the F.E...

I thought very shortly, so nevermind this one.